# VBA User Form issue select wrong sheet

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to achieve is to create a User Form which I call in Sheet1, but the results from the VBA user form should go to sheet 2 rows without open it. However I am not able to achieve that, when I save the records the sheet 2 pop ups. Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks a lot.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate






'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = OptionButton1.Caption
End If

If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = OptionButton2.Caption
End If

If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = OptionButton3.Caption
End If




If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = CheckBox1.Caption

If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox2.Caption

If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox3.Caption

If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox4.Caption

If CheckBox5.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox5.Caption

Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & TextBox3.Value


If CheckBox6.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox6.Caption

If CheckBox7.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value & " " & CheckBox7.Caption

If CheckBox8.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value & " " & CheckBox8.Caption

 'ewwrewerwerwe

If OptionButton7.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = OptionButton7.Caption
End If

If OptionButton8.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = OptionButton8.Caption
End If

If OptionButton9.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = OptionButton9.Caption
End If

'werwewewewe

If OptionButton10.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = OptionButton10.Caption
End If

If OptionButton11.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = OptionButton11.Caption
End If

If OptionButton12.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = OptionButton12.Caption
End If


'ewrweewwerew

If OptionButton13.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton13.Caption
End If

If OptionButton14.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton14.Caption
End If

If OptionButton15.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton15.Caption
End If

If OptionButton16.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton16.Caption
End If

If OptionButton17.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton17.Caption
End If

'werwerwerwe

If OptionButton18.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton18.Caption
End If

If OptionButton19.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton19.Caption
End If

If OptionButton20.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton20.Caption
End If

If OptionButton21.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton21.Caption
End If

If OptionButton22.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton22.Caption
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Your first command: `Sheets("Sheet2").Activate` will show you Sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

rather than activating the sheet use a With statement and then ref it with .cells --- whilst in the with (e.g. before the end with) you can ref the sheet and normal sheet functions with just a "." first e.g. .range("A1").value would get the value from sheet2 A1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
With Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1

    'Transfer information

    .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value

    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = OptionButton1.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = OptionButton2.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = OptionButton3.Caption
    End If




    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = CheckBox1.Caption

    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox2.Caption

    If CheckBox3.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox3.Caption

    If CheckBox4.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox4.Caption

    If CheckBox5.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & CheckBox5.Caption

    .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value & " " & TextBox3.Value


    If CheckBox6.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox6.Caption

    If CheckBox7.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value & " " & CheckBox7.Caption

    If CheckBox8.Value = True Then .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value & " " & CheckBox8.Caption

     'ewwrewerwerwe

    If OptionButton7.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = OptionButton7.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton8.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = OptionButton8.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton9.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = OptionButton9.Caption
    End If

    'werwewewewe

    If OptionButton10.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = OptionButton10.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton11.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = OptionButton11.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton12.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = OptionButton12.Caption
    End If


    'ewrweewwerew

    If OptionButton13.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton13.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton14.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton14.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton15.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton15.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton16.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton16.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton17.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = OptionButton17.Caption
    End If

    'werwerwerwe

    If OptionButton18.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton18.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton19.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton19.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton20.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton20.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton21.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton21.Caption
    End If

    If OptionButton22.Value = True Then
        .Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = OptionButton22.Caption
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Another option would be to turn screenupdating off and then slect the original sheet before turning it back on but above is more effcient